# Recieve and reply to sms on huawei modem, gammu-smsd: Process failed with exit status 2

Tags: bash, unicode, sms, modem, gammu

I Have a Huawei E220 HSDPA Modem on linux xubuntu
I wanted to recieve sms and reply automatically to the sender.
I Use gammu and Gammu-smsd to do this.

To automatically send sms back I added runOnRecieve = /path/to/bash/file into the /etc/gammu-smsdrc configuration-file.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
str=$SMS_1_TEXT //string containing text from sender
tlf=$SMS_1_NUMBER //containing number from sender
tlf=${tlf:3}


if test "$str" = "today"; then

   echo "[Weather for today in Norway]
   Sol, noe overskyet
   [Vind fra sørøst]
   Ha en fin dag!" | gammu-smsd-inject TEXT $tlf -unicode -autolen 200
else
   echo "fail" >> /home/mattis/sms.txt
fi
```

This is how I start the daemon

```
$ sudo gammu-smsd
```

This works if I run the bash script from terminal using test-input, but when the program gammu-smsd calls the script I get.

```
gammu-smsd[3183]: Process failed with exit status 2
```

Now i can remove "gammu-smsd-inject" from the code and replace with "gammu sendsms" , but that would just give me gibberish letters instead of "æøå and [ ]" when received back to the mobile.

Hoping for positive answers.

Comment: even I encounter this issue, I filled already https://github.com/gammu/gammu/issues/39

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**--/*/*--Working code--/*/*--**

The thing is: Gammu sms inject acctually sends data to mysql database called smsd.

**Creating this database:**
This should be created as specified in [wammu sql database](http://wammu.eu/docs/manual/smsd/mysql.html). Storing the SQL script for creating tables in MySQL database will able you to import it with phpmyadmin(gui) or any other way to interface mysql.

**Run on recieve**
Add to the end of /etc/gammu-smsdrc --configuration file for gammu

```
runOnRecieve = /path/to/bash/file
```

**Open the /path/to/bash/file**

```
#!/bin/bash
str=$SMS_1_TEXT //codeword "weather"
tlf=$SMS_1_NUMBER //+47 41412424
tlf=${tlf:3} //remove +47

if test "$tlf" = "41412424"; then
    toSend = "[Weather for today in Norway]"
else
    toSend = "[you are not part of this group]"
    echo "Someone outside the group send to this number" > /home/user/activity.txt
fi

mysql --host=localhost --user=username --password=pw smsd << EOF
INSERT INTO outbox (
   DestinationNumber,
   TextDecoded,
   CreatorID,
   RelativeValidity
) VALUES (
   '$tlf',
   '$toSend',
   'Program',
   '255'
);
EOF
```

**Start the daemon**

```
$ sudo gammu-smsd
```

That should be it!

**Extra tips:**

- Use `$ gammu-detect` to find out where the device is connected. Look for `name = Phone on USB serial port HUAWEI_Technology HUAWEI_Mobile` or something similar. Put this info in the configfile.
- Be shure to add right permission to the bashfile. Make it readable to user running gammu-smsd.
- Make the bashfile executable using chmod u+x /path/to/bash/file.
- The gammu-smsd-monitor can be used to check how good signal you have. Be shure not to stop running the gammu-smsd when trying to run this.
- You can test the bashfile by running it with dummy tlf and dummytext as input. `$ ./bashfile.sh`.